# Cofinality in the definition of subnets

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, nets

Why is cofinality required in the definition of a subnet? My professor mentioned that there are certain cardinality-related reasons for this requirement. Does this have anything to do with the confinality of cardinal numbers?

Comment: Cardinals aren't involved in the definitions of nets or subnets. The same general definition of *cofinal subset* makes sense for directed sets, and cardinals are directed sets. I doubt your professor was alluding to more advanced notions like "true cofinality", which do involve cardinals.

Comment: Have you actually seen any proofs of theorems about subnets?  How nets and subnets can be used to characterize topology.  Look at the proofs and you'll see where cofinality is used.  It's not a definition that exists in a vacuum.

Comment: Start by reviewing the notion of limits of sequences. You will see something like "... there exists $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$....". Now relate this to the notion of cofinality for nets.

Comment: You should add the precise definition of a subnet.